# Cannot find/connect to RPI from desktop, but CAN from phone

Tags: connection

I'm running OctoPrint (3D printing software) from my rpi3. I just changed apartments, connected to the wifi via my config file, and it works great BUT I can only connect via my phone. My desktop (connected via Ethernet cable to the same Ethernet switch as the access point is) cannot find the IP of the pi nor connected to OctoPrint.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The connection with phone is only to the `OctoPrint` or you have tried to connect via `ssh`? have you tried to scan the net from your desktop?

Comment: Francesco, I have tried ssh from my computer at the address I see on my pi after running ifconfig. I have tried scanning the network with angry up scanner, and not come up with the pi either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't totally find the answer, but I figured out a work around:

I think something with my router isn't working as I'd like (DCHP or something) and since I don't have access to the settings (friend's house) I switched to ethernet. While on ethernet, my computer could access the RPI IP address, and run octoprint well.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.